# Interesting C++ operator overloading problem

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I made a Matrix class on my own. but there is interesting problem when overloading + operator.

```
Matrix Matrix::operator+ (Matrix& operand)
{
    if(row_size == operand.row_size && col_size == operand.col_size)
    {
        Matrix temp(row_size, col_size);
        for(int i = 0; i < col_size; i ++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < row_size; j ++)
            {
                temp[i][j] = data_list[i][j] + operand.data_list[i][j];
            }
        }

        return temp;
    }
    else
        throw Error::Matrix_error(0);
}
```

When I do

`matrix + matrix2;`

on main function, it seems like the program is in a infinite loop. So, I just debugged it and found out that the code stops at `return temp;` part. 
I have no idea why this function cannot return `temp` since return type of operator+ is `Matrix`.

Plus, this code totally works well when I compile in a RELEASE mode (visual studio 2010). However it does not work when I compile in a DEBUG mode.

Comment: what does the copy-ctor (or assignment) of `Matrix` look like?

Comment: What do you mean by "the code **stops** at `return temp;`"?  Do you mean that it crashes?

Comment: Allocate space for the matrix dynamically and try returning a pointer to the matrix.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth I mean, the debug pointer does not move forward when it reaches 'return temp'

Comment: @SpeedBirdNine: Why would you do that?  That would result in horrendous semantics.

Comment: @DanS: For `operator+=` maybe.  Not for `operator+` (although typically you'd implement one in terms of the other).

Comment: Operators that are not to be mutated should be passed by value or as const reference. Also, your `operator+` should be a const member function, because it does not change the observable behaviour of your matrix object. See http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/const-correctness.html and make it part of you as a good C++ programmer. Apart from that: You might have bad copy construction and/or copy-assignment. Post them, or better, post the whole matrix class.

Comment: thx @Nim. It was the problem on copy constructor. Thx a lot!

Comment: @SpeedBirdNine: Uhm, no, he really shouldn't. In C++, we only seldomly allocate dynamically, because we usually don't have to.

Comment: Thanks, @Lee for pasting actual code and not pseudo-code. But, since your program is incomplete, it is unnecessarily difficult to provide an answer. Would you please post a minimal, complete program that demonstrates your problem? For more information on this debugging technique, see http://sscce.org/.

Comment: @Lee Jae Beom: You are encouraged to answer your own question and accept that as the answer that fits you the best. This will also help future visitors of this site.

Comment: @phresnel: Usually, yes.  But I'd advocate closing this particular question as "too localized"...

Answer (score -1):

The problem was I miss created copy constructor. It looks like it fell on infinite loop at copy constructor but the debugger didn't catch it.

Comment: the `@`-answers should be comments where you've been asked ;)